# Reduce output from docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

Is it possible to reduce the output from `docker build` so that warnings etc are still shown, but not the very verbose default output such as the below?

I have a script that builds 15 images and it just becomes useless to follow the outcome of it. If everything is OK I want no output, but I do want the warnings.

The `--quiet` flag to `docker build` removes everything. I also tried redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` but keeping `stderr`, but then also warnings are suppressed (for example warnings from optional modules using `node-gyp` failing due to missing `python` etc - I *do* want to see those).

Is there any way to only log warnings?

Example output to *exclude*:

```
 docker build: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 docker build: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 docker build: (1/27) Installing make (4.2.1-r2)
 docker build: (2/27) Installing binutils (2.33.1-r0)
 docker build: (3/27) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
 docker build: (4/27) Installing isl (0.18-r0)
 docker build: (5/27) Installing libgomp (9.3.0-r0)
 [ ... ]
 docker build: OK: 232 MiB in 43 packages
 docker build: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 docker build: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 docker build: OK: 232 MiB in 43 packages
 docker build: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
```

Example output to *include*:

```
 docker build: warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/usr/app/node_modules/unix-dgram: Command failed.

 docker build: gyp ERR! find Python 
 docker build: gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
```

Perhaps the node-gyp module is simply the culprit using stdout for warnings/errors?

Is there any better bet than piping through `grep -E -i "warn|err"` and hoping all relevant warnings are prefixed?

Comment: option -l warning should do what you want .. by default, -l info is used